# Python: out of range list for random creation of alphabet

Tags: python-2.7

I want to create a random alphabet. So my code is the following:

```
alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

def new_alphabet():
    for i in range(0, 26):
        j = 25
        my_new_alphabet = [None] * 26
        my_new_alphabet[i] = alphabet[random.randint(0, j)]
        alphabet.remove(my_new_alphabet[i])
        j = j-1
   return my_new_alphabet
print new_alphabet()
```

But when I try to execute it:

```
my_new_alphabet[i] = alphabet[random.randint(0, j)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It is probably something fairly simple but I cannot manage to find where the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

- your  `alphabet` is missing the letter `"S"`, so it has only 25 elements, thus the ranges for your loop and for your random indices are one-off, thus the out-of-range error
- the lines `j = 25` and `my_new_alphabet = [None] * 26` should go *before* the loop, otherwise you are resetting them in each iteration

Also, you could drop `j` entirely and just use the bounds of the actual `alphabet` list instead:

```
def new_alphabet():
    my_new_alphabet = []
    while alphabet:
        letter = alphabet[random.randint(0, len(alphabet) - 1)]:
        # or just use this: letter = random.choice(alphabet)
        alphabet.remove(letter)
        my_new_alphabet.append(letter)
    return my_new_alphabet
```

Or just use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle), which does exactly what you want:

```
def new_alphabet():
    my_new_alphabet = list(alphabet) # copy
    random.shuffle(my_new_alphabet)
    return my_new_alphabet
```